# How to draw an audio waveform on Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I have a custom view that I want to use to display the amplitude of audio coming in through the microphone in a line graph.
Getting the amplitude and all that I have no problem with, and drawing the lines is not really a problem either.

What I want to do is show the amplitude starting at the far right edge, moving left. So with each new sample I want to translate the bitmap to the left, then draw a line from the last point to the new point. I'm not sure what the easiest way to achieve this is. I originally was able to do it by drawing Paths and just adding a new point to the path with each sample, the problem was that after like a minute the path was too big to be drawn. So I thought about it and wanted to switch to using a cached bitmap, translate that on each iteration, and draw from the last point to the new point. However this is tricky to do as (after experimentation). When I translate the bitmap it doesn't move the far left pixels off the bitmap, it just moves the entire bitmap in the canvas and I have no way to write pixels to the right side. 
Below is a description of what I'm trying to do:

Given this:
[image]

I want to translate that to the left:
[image]

Then draw a line to a new point the space space on the right
[image]

Of course, step 2 and 3 should happen at essentially the same time.

How can I achieve this? I'm open to new ideas altogether, like perhaps saving all the points for up to 1 screen worth and drawing them out on each onDraw call. I'd prefer to just save them in a bitmap and do some kind of translation/clipping etc to achieve the same thing with perhaps less overhead.

```
private static final int MAX_AMPLITUDE = 32767;
float lx, ly;
private Paint mPaint;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;

private void init() {

    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.Black);
}

 @Override
public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    if (mBitmap != null) {
        mBitmap.recycle();
    }
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    height = h;
    width = w;
    ly = height;
    lx = width;
    amplitudeDivisor = ((float) MAX_AMPLITUDE / (float) height);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    mAmplitude = (float)(MAX_AMPLITUDE * Math.random());
    float dx = width - delta;
    float dy = height - (mAmplitude / amplitudeDivisor);
    mCanvas.drawLine(lx, ly, dx, dy, mPaint);
    mCanvas.translate(-delta, 0);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);
    lx = dx;
    ly = dy;
    delta+=10;
    postInvalidateDelayed(200);

}
```

The above is just a sample, I'm just using a random value for the amplitude to simplify for now. I've tried a bunch of things with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Lol tell me about it.

Comment: I should have been a graphics artist. =p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting this working by saving the points to an array. I draw a white line before the recording starts. Note that I use an EvictingQueue from the Guava library as a circular buffer of points to render on a line. To use this, once a recording starts call start() and when it ends call stop.  From your activity you will need to send MediaRecorder getMaxAmplitude() values to the updateAmplitude() method of this class, and do so at an interval of say 50 ms. The view also supports rotation.

```
public class AmplitudeWaveFormView extends View {
    private static final String TAG = AmplitudeWaveFormView.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int MAX_AMPLITUDE = 32767;
    private static final int SAMPLES_PER_SCREEN = 100;
    private float mAmplitude = 0;

    private Paint mRecordingPaint, mNotRecordingPaint;
    private int height = -1;
    private int width = -1;
    private boolean mIsStarted;

    private float[] lastPoints;

    private int oldWidth = -1, oldHeight = -1;
    private int mCurrentSample;
    private float amplitudeDivisor = 1;
    private float lx,ly, deltaX;


    private EvictingQueue<Float> mPointQueue;


    private int recordColor;

    private int notRecordingColor;


    public AmplitudeWaveFormView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public AmplitudeWaveFormView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public AmplitudeWaveFormView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }


    public void start() {
        mIsStarted = true;
    }


    public void stop() {
        mIsStarted = false;
    }
    public void updateAmplitude(float amplitude) {
        mAmplitude = amplitude;
        postInvalidate();
    }

    private void init() {
        recordColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.mint);
        notRecordingColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.alpine);
        mRecordingPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mRecordingPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mRecordingPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        mRecordingPaint.setColor(recordColor);

        mNotRecordingPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mNotRecordingPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mNotRecordingPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        mNotRecordingPaint.setColor(notRecordingColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        height = h;
        width = w;
        ly = height;
        lx = width;
        deltaX =  (float)width / (float)SAMPLES_PER_SCREEN;
        amplitudeDivisor = ((float) MAX_AMPLITUDE / (float) height);

        mPointQueue = EvictingQueue.create(SAMPLES_PER_SCREEN * 4);
        if (lastPoints != null && lastPoints.length > 0) {
            float xScale = (float) width/oldWidth;
            float yScale = (float) height/oldHeight;
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.setScale(xScale, yScale);
            matrix.mapPoints(lastPoints);
            mPointQueue.addAll(Floats.asList(lastPoints));
            ly = lastPoints[lastPoints.length-1];
            lx= lastPoints[lastPoints.length -2];
            lastPoints = null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        if (state instanceof Bundle) {
            Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
            mCurrentSample = bundle.getInt("sample");
            lastPoints = bundle.getFloatArray("lines");
            oldWidth = bundle.getInt("oldWidth");
            oldHeight = bundle.getInt("oldHeight");
            state = ((Bundle) state).getParcelable("parent");

        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putFloatArray("lines", Floats.toArray(mPointQueue));
        bundle.putInt("sample", mCurrentSample);
        bundle.putParcelable("parent", super.onSaveInstanceState());
        bundle.putInt("oldWidth", width);
        bundle.putInt("oldHeight", height);
        return bundle;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (mIsStarted) {
            float x = lx + deltaX;
            float y = height - (mAmplitude / amplitudeDivisor);
            mPointQueue.add(lx);
            mPointQueue.add(ly);
            mPointQueue.add(x);
            mPointQueue.add(y);
            lastPoints = Floats.toArray(mPointQueue);
            lx = x;
            ly = y;
        }
        if (lastPoints != null && lastPoints.length > 0) {
            int len = mPointQueue.size() / 4 >= SAMPLES_PER_SCREEN ? SAMPLES_PER_SCREEN * 4 : mPointQueue.size();
            float translateX = width - lastPoints[lastPoints.length - 2];
            canvas.translate(translateX, 0);
            canvas.drawLines(lastPoints, 0, len, mRecordingPaint);
        }

        if (mCurrentSample <= SAMPLES_PER_SCREEN) {
            drawNotRecordingLine(canvas);
        }
        mCurrentSample++;
    }

    private void drawNotRecordingLine(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawLine(0,height, width, height, mNotRecordingPaint);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to create wave form and I want to use this code, but I don't understand what is `EvictingQueue`? can you post the content of this class?

Comment: Google is your friend! That's a pun and it was intended.

Comment: @AshishTiwari add compile 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0-android'